# Issue with translucent Terrain (Probably Depth Buffer issues)

Tags: c#, opengl, rendering, opentk, depth-buffer

I have issues with rendering. The Blocks im rendering are somewhat translucent. Everything is fine as long as im using Nvidia Graphics Cards. On Intel (integrated) or AMD Graphics Cards it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see there are blocks being rendered, that should be behind others.

This are my prepare methods.

```
    public void prepare()
    {
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
        GL.ClearColor(skyColour.X, skyColour.Y, skyColour.Z, 0f);
    }

    public void enableGLCaps()
    {
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthClamp);

        GL.Enable(EnableCap.CullFace);
        GL.CullFace(CullFaceMode.Back);

        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);
        GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactor.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactor.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
    }
```

This is my vertex shader:

```
#version 440
in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;

out vec2 pass_textureCoords;
out float visibility;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform float density;
uniform float gradient;

void main() {
    vec4 worldPosition = transformationMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    vec4 positionRelativeToCam = viewMatrix * worldPosition;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * positionRelativeToCam;

    pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;
    float distance = length(positionRelativeToCam.xyz);
    visibility = exp(-pow((distance*density), gradient));
    visibility = clamp(visibility, 0.0, 1.0);

}
```

And here my fragment shader:

```
#version 440

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;
uniform vec3 skyColour;

in vec2 pass_textureCoords;
in float visibility;

out vec4 color;

void main() {

    vec4 textureColour = texture(textureSampler, pass_textureCoords);
    if (textureColour.a < 0.5)
        discard;

    color = mix(vec4(skyColour, 1.0), textureColour, visibility);
    color.a = 1;
}
```

Changing the near plane doesnt help.

EDIT 1:

I have rendered the z value and have noticed, that some faces definitely dont have the correct value. 
I am rendering every texture in a region (16*16*16 chunks) as a single VAO (will use texture atlases later, but im running into flickering/overlapping with mipmapping using it). The Faces, that are rendered as one VAO are not overlapping each other so the z buffer seems to be ok there. It looks like its being retested after every render call. 
Here is my render call:

```
GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.Quads, vertices, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);
```

SOLUTION:

The depth function I was using was wrong. You should be using Lequal. I also had to set the depth range to (0, 1).

Comment: I'd check the value of `pow(x,y)`. It may be undefined if `x<0` or `x==0 && y<=0` In other words, some imprecision for different drivers on `distance*density` calculation.

Comment: That isnt the issue unfortunately. Ive removed everything but the three matrix multiplications and the texture function in the fragment shader. Still the same result.
Ive rendered the Z value and there are many Faces not rendering in the color they are supposed to (many are rendered white = near, even tho they are far away). So i think its definitely an issue with the depth buffer.

Comment: See the edit for more information.

Comment: it might be also driver problem ... I got similar problems on AMD and Intel while rendering into texture and use result on semitransparent object. Intel is not capable of rendering to texture (other than ugly slow CPU/GPU side transfers) and AMD has problems with rendering correctly. The only work around I found is to not use rendering to texture at all on both vendors. But it does not look like you  are rendering to texture so it might be entirely different issue (however I suspect its related)

Comment: what z value have you rendered? Depth or space camera? Also your atmospheric fog computation should only take into account `positionRelativeToCam.z`, which contains the depth or distance from the camera to the vertex